# Using an mySQL Database from another network

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I created a mySQL database on one machine in my local network. Lets say, I install my application on a friends computer at his house. I have a computer set up as a server running the mySQL database at my house. If that computer is running, how can I make my friends computer send and receive data from the mySQL database on my network?

I am using JDBC and the J connector. I currently can connect to the database with JDBC, so I am currently good with that.

How can I make my friends computer send and receive data from the mySQL database on my network? Will I need a service like [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction) or is there any other free way?I also want to make it so that I can email any friend with the program, and they can install it and the program connects to the MySQL server without Andy router extensional. Is a MySQL database even the way to go?

Edit: Basically, I made an MySQL database on a local computer and am able to save data to it from a JDBC program. I want the SQL database to be online so if I send the program to somebody else, they can open it and it accesses the online database. How should I go about making an online SQL database which has no limitations on what IP address accesses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a NAT router connecting your local network to the Internet, set up port forwarding on your router to forward port 3306 to the database machine on your network.

Then your friend would specify your router's public IP as the hostname when making the database connection.

In your MySQL configuration, you'll need to create a user `username@your-friend's-IP`, and grant it access to your your database tables.

Comment: Also static ip of friend's machine is eaiser for everyday usage.

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL client (the thing running on your friend's local network) initiates a connection to a MySQL server by requesting a TCP connection on port 3306 (usually).

So your friend's computer has to be able to initiate a connection to your computer. Most home networks have routers between them and the internet service provided. Routers, unless specially configured, ignore attempts to connect from the public internet.

You need to configure your router to pass port 3306 connections through to your computer. Then you need to figure out the ip address by which your internet service provider addresses your router and your friend's router (usually the router user interface will tell you this).  Then you need to set up a username /  ip address / password triple on your MySQL database authorizing your friend to connect.

Finally, keep in mind that your internet service provider probably assigns both of you dynamic ip addresses; they might change.

Comment: The question never said that his network was a home network, just the friend's.